# ipscanner python3 (module ipaddress). result list - all hosts offline

Tags: python-3.x

There is a code to scan the specified range of addresses:

```html
import os, ipaddress
position_start=input('Start hostname: ')
position_end=input('End hostname: ')
hostname_start = ipaddress.IPv4Address(position_start)
hostname_end = ipaddress.IPv4Address(position_end)
while hostname_start <= hostname_end:
    hostname_response = os.system("ping -c 1 -w 2" + str(hostname_start)+ "> /dev/null 2>&1")
    if hostname_response == 0:
        print (hostname_start, ' is up!\n')
    else:
        print (hostname_start, ' is down!\n')
    hostname_start += 1
input("\nPress the enter key to exit...")
```

Result its work - all hosts in subnetwork are offline

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is formatting string. `"ping -c 1 -w 2"` have no space at the end and application can't found ip address. Here's working example

```
import os
import ipaddress

position_start = input('Start hostname: ')
position_end = input('End hostname: ')
hostname_start = ipaddress.IPv4Address(position_start)
hostname_end = ipaddress.IPv4Address(position_end)


while hostname_start <= hostname_end:
    hostname_response = os.system("ping -c 1 -w 2 {0} > /dev/null 2>&1".format(hostname_start))
    if hostname_response == 0:
        print(hostname_start, ' is up!\n')
    else:
        print(hostname_start, ' is down!\n')
    hostname_start += 1

input("\nPress the enter key to exit...")
```

Note, that this example will work only on Linux, cause `-w` ping option isn't supported on *BSD and OS X.

Comment: Also note, in real word escape shell params with [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).